# The closure of a singleton is path-connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $x$ be in an element of topological space $X$. Prove that the closure of $\{x\}$ is path connected.

I am having issues creating a path, and I have a bit of difficulty understanding "the closure of $\{x\}$".

Comment: What is an element ?

Comment: @gnometorule What if the set $\{x\}$ is not closed in the topology?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I gave you +1, and removed my comment with tail between my legs...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews could you explain to me how the closure of a point is defined?

Comment: It should be the smallest closed set containing {x}

Comment: @mathlove It is defined as the intersection of all the closed sets that contain that point. It is the "smallest" closed set that contains that point. There exist topologies in which singletons are not closed, however, so it is not always true that the closure of $\{x\}$ is $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any point $y\in \overline{\{x\}}$ and consider the curve $\gamma\colon[0,1] \to X$ defined by
$$
\gamma(t) = \begin{cases}y &\text{when $t=0$}\\x &\text{when $t>0$}\end{cases}
$$
it is enough to prove that $\gamma$ is continuous.

For $t>0$ the function is constant hence continuous. For $t=0$ take any neighbourhood $U$ of $y$. Since $y\in \overline{\{x\}}$ then $U\cap\{x\}\neq \emptyset$ hence $x\in U$. So $\gamma([0,1]) = \{x,y\} \subset $U$.

Comment: What if $\{y\}$ is closed?

Comment: What I meant was, that the preimage of $y$ must be closed, if $y$ is closed.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think answerer needs to swap $x,y$ in the definition. @StefanH.

Comment: If $x$ is not closed, then it is not closed in $\{x,y\}$ either, so we don't have to worry about its preimage in $I$. But $y$ could still be closed in this two-element set.

Comment: More generally, if $y,z\in\overline{\{x\}}$, $$\gamma(t) = \begin{cases}y &\text{when }t=0\\x &\text{when }0<t<1\\z&\text{when }t=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's good. It considers the cases $y$ or $z$ closed, and also that $x$ is open.

Comment: It also, of course, handles the case when $x$ is closed, since then $y=z=x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Wow, I didn't think about that case ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: thanks... I didn't notice the asymmetry. I made the correction with a temptative proof.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this nice [overview on finite spaces](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/FiniteSpaces.pdf), especially theorem 4.8, which states that for a finite topological space, path connectedness is equivalent to connectedness. And the closure of a singleton is clearly connected as the closure of a connected set.

In fact, when $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$, (or $x \le y$ in the notation of the paper), the function that sends $t < 1$ to $x$ and $1$ to $y$ is a continuous path from $x$ to $y$ showing that $x$ and $y$ are in the same path component, see lemma 4.7.

Comment: The space $X$ is not assumed finite.

Comment: I use the proof, not the finiteness